Collapse and expand a view based on scrollview
I have this custom top bar and i want to collapse and expand a section in the top bar based on the scroll of scroll view to achieve something like the collapsing top bar in youtube.
I have tried a geometry reader, but very unreliable, it animates way past what its should.

ScrollViewReader { proxy in
     ScrollView {      
         VStack(spacing: 0) {
                   //Content
         }
    }
}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .top, spacing: 0){
//Topbar
VStack{
      Text(“title”)
    
//this section need to expand and collapse based on the scroll
   VStack{

      Text(“title”)

      Button(action: {
            action()
        }) {
            Text(title)
        }
    }
}
}


